# show grid out of parent borders

Tags: delphi

I have a GroupBox with width=130 and height=130, containing a TEdit and a Grid with visible=false. When text is entered in the TEdit I want the Grid to be visible (together it looks like a column combobox).

The problem is: the grid does not fit in the groupbox.

How can I show grid out of groupbox borders witout change in groupbox borders.

Pseudocode:

```
if Edit.Text <>'' then
begin
dbgrid.height :=260 
end
else
begin
dbgrid.Height :=0;
end;
```

Comment: Hikmat, I rewrote your question, hope it is clearer now. I understand that English is not your first language, that is fine, but you should take care to properly describe stuff, e.g. name the component types. From your original question text it is not clear if it is a TStringGrid or TDBGrid. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Can't you just assign to the `Height` and `Width` properties of the group box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `Visible` property instead of setting the `Height` to 0.

If you want to display the grid outside the client rect of the group box you have to change the parent, for example:

```
dbgrid.Parent := GetParentForm(groupbox);
```

Note that the component position must then be specified in the client coordinate system of the new parent:

```
// coordinates in groupbox coordinate system
GridPopupPt := Point(edit.Left, edit.Top + edit.Height);

// coordinates in parent coordinate system
GridPopupPt := groupbox.ClientToParent(GridPopupPt, GetParentForm(groupbox));   

dbgrid.Left := GridPopupPt.X;
dbgrid.Top := GridPopupPt.Y;
```

With this solution, the grid still cannot grow beyond the current form. If you need this, you would have to create a completely independent form with the grid as the only component.

Comment: i need the opesite case i want the gride to send front the groupbox and show all the grid without change in groupbox borders

Comment: That's exactly what this answer provides. Why don't you try it?